# How could I distinguish contributors on crowdsale?

Tags: accounts, ico

lets say that I will conduct a crowdsale from my website instead of selling our tokens form stellar decentralized exchange.

lets say I have two investors A and B and they will send their XLM to our Stellar account in the same time, **How could I distinguish who is A and Who is B ?**

suggested solutions:

- is to have multiple stellar account so that we can now know the one who sends to account B and who sends to account A.
- ask the user from which public address he will send his contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can create new accounts for each investor, indeed but storing new passwords all the time in your system in a safe way can become very challenging. [BIP32 key derivation](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/exp/crypto/derivation) can help with that. You may need to create the accounts on the network and fund them to make it simpler for the senders.
- A more common concept is to make use of the [memo](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#memo) field. You would assign an unique identifier to the investor and let them put that as memo into the transaction. Then you can easily identify incoming transactions and assign them to the right investor.
- On top of that, you can also setup a [federation server](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/federation.html) and let the wallets resolve the destination addressID and memo field value via a unique name you had assigned to each investor.

Comment: Thanks alot, I already considered the last two points, but the first point "create new accounts for each investor" will cost a seed XLM for account activation for each account. and that will be really costly.